# Can I combine two separate outdoor lights onto one three way switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Currently I have two outdoor lights on two separate switches. I would like to have them both on the same switch and be able to turn on with either switch location. Can a three way switch be added at each location and three way wiring be run between the switches?

Comment: Please give more information about your scenario. As it is, you're simply asking "can wiring be changed?".

Answer (score 0):

This is of course doable, almost everything is, but not dead simple.

The details will depend on the existing wiring, whether the existing lights are on the same or different circuits, and whether the switch boxes have neutrals in them.  There are probably too many possible variables to give solid step by step instructions, but you'll probably have to

- run wiring from switch box to switch box
- replace the existing switches with 3-way switches
- possibly run wiring to get a neutral for the circuit into the switch boxes
- possibly replace the switch boxes with larger boxes

If there are neutrals available in both switch boxes, it may be worth doing with smart switches - switches that communicate by wireless or over the power lines, and can be programmed to do the same thing three way switches do.  The switches will cost more, and they have to be programmed, but you'll save the cost and trouble of running wire, and you may think of other uses for smart switches etc. in your home.